# WPF datagrid display select row to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

to be honest I've searched Everywhere but can't seem to find a solution, what I'm trying to achieve is when a person selects a WPF datagrid the contents gets displayed in the concurrent textboxes. this is the code I tried but it's only  displaying the raw data.. like (SalesManagementSystem.Models.Customer). Can anyone help me out please..i have tried everything..what am i missing??

```
public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
    {
        var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
        if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
        foreach (var item in itemsSource)
        {
            var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
            if (null != row) yield return row;
        }
    }

    private void DgCustomerInfo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var row_list = GetDataGridRows(customersPage.dgCustomerInfo);
            foreach (DataGridRow single_row in row_list)
            {
                if (single_row.IsSelected == true)
                {

                    customersPage.txtCustomerName.Text=single_row.Item.ToString();

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Override `.ToString()` in your `SalesManagementSystem.Models.Customer` class to specify how & what you want to display.

Comment: aahh thank you,I really appreciate it, let me try that

Comment: You can also cast `single_row.Item` to `SalesManagementSystem.Models.Customer` to display necessary data.

Comment: Casting doesn't seem to work..